# How can I find out if two strings are mostly equal (in perl)?

Tags: perl, search, correlation, similarity

I have a string that I want to compare against an array of strings, and return the array element that most closely matches.

I can write a sliding correlator that counts the number of matching characters at each step and returns the max correlation.  But is there a better way?

For example:
control_string = drv_probability_1_max

List:
    burst_period_min/max
    duty_cycle_min/max
    probablility_0_min/max
    probablility_1_min/max

Where ideally it returns "probablility_1_min/max"

Comment: Didn't Knuth devote several chapters of one of his books to this?

Comment: I don't know...I haven't read any of Knuth's books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`String::Approx`](http://p3rl.org/String%3a%3aApprox);

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for the [`String::Similarity`](http://p3rl.org/String::Similarity) module.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Text::Levenshtein](http://search.cpan.org/~jgoldberg/Text-Levenshtein-0.05/Levenshtein.pm) or [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.37/lib/List/Compare.pm) (String::Approx is the same method, but a more complete package)

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);

my $ctl = "drv_probability_1_max";

my @list=qw|
burst_period_min/max
duty_cycle_min/max
probablility_0_min/max
probablility_1_min/max
|;

my @dist=distance($ctl,@list);

print "Levenshtein distances: @dist\n";

my $idmin=0;
$dist[$idmin] < $dist[$_] or $idmin = $_ for 1..$#dist;

print "\"$list[$idmin]\" seems the closest...\n\n\n";
```

Output:

```
Levenshtein distances: 16 16 10 9
"probablility_1_min/max" seems the closest...
```

Read more about [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or [implement](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Perl) a Perl algorithm directly..